# Using parentheses in input string for regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to add items to a multi line `TextBox`. The  `TextBox` should not take duplicate lines. If a duplicate is present then it should rename it to `name (1)`. I am using Regex for this purpose.

Following is my function:

```
private string Rename(string input, string[] lines)
{
    string output = string.Empty;
    if (lines.Contains(input))
    {
        Regex regEx = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", input), RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
        string[] str = lines.Select(x => x).Where(y => regEx.IsMatch(y)).ToArray();
        regEx = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}\b \(\d+\)", input));
        string[] matchedStrings = str.Select(x => x).Where(y => regEx.IsMatch(y)).ToArray();
        if (matchedStrings.Length > 0)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} ({1})", input, (matchedStrings.Length + 1));
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Format("{0} (1)", input, matchedStrings.Length);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

This is how I call the function in a button click:

```
// textBox2 is a multiline text bor. textBox1 is where the input is taken from
textBox2.Text += Rename(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Lines) + Environment.NewLine;
```

The above code works for normal text. For example:

if `input` is `abc` and same `input` is given again, it returns `abc (1)`. After this if I give input as `abc (1)`, then the first regex pattern returns zero matches. Because of this, I am unable to rename appropriately.

Comment: Do I get it right that you call your method like `Rename("abc", new[] {"abc", "abc"})`?

Comment: i pass `TextBox.Lines` as second parameter

Comment: Then please provide some sample call with expected output. Why do you return a string and not a string list/array? I understand you may have `lines` like `new[] {"abc", "abc (2)", "def"}`? And when you pass `abc` as input, you want to get a "abc (4)\ndef" string?

Comment: Because, the input string is validated against the second parameter and modified if it exists. Why would I return a list?

Comment: I understand you may have `lines` like `new[] {"abc", "abc (2)", "def"}`? And when you pass `abc` as input, you want to get a `"abc (4)\ndef"` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `input` when injecting it to a regex:

```
//                                                vvvvvvvvvvvvv     v
Regex regEx = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(input)), RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

When `input` is `abc (1)`, without escaping the regex becomes `\babc (1)\b`. See? The parentheses are unescaped, which makes literal `(1)` string a pattern of literal `1` captured in a group.

Please note the `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` you're using does not make parentheses treated literally. This option only tells the regex engine to use parentheses for grouping and not for capturing.

As a rule of thumb, do always escape strings injected into a regex.

The second issue is the closing `\b` fails to match after closing `)`. `)` is not considered a word character so end of string after `)` is not a word boundary. To fix it you may supply the closing `\b` with an alternative matching anything prepended by a `)`. This may be put as `(?<=\))`, which is an empty string preceded by a `)`. So the regex initialisation turns to:

```
//                                           v  vvvvvvvvv
Regex regEx = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}(\b|(?<=\)))", Regex.Escape(input)), RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

Comment: I doubt this will help OP since the code does not seem to be doing what OP needs. Besides, `\b` is not what OP needs if the whole *lines* must match. And another point is that `\babc \(1\)\b` will match in `abc (1)abc` and not in `abc (1)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I believe the unescaped parentheses is the main (or probably the first) issue since the OP states _" if I give input as `abc (1)`, then the first regex pattern returns zero matches"_. I intended to get back with the OP code review in a while to counter any further issues.

Comment: @Abhishek: This is because the closing `\b` fails to match after closing `)`.  `)` is not considered a word character so end of string after `)` is not a word boundary. We need to clarify the requirements to fix the issue. Is `lines` expected to contain values such `abc (1)def` and `abc (1) def` (the latter with a space before `def` and the former without one.) If so, what is the expected result of `Rename("abc (1)", new [] { "abc (1)def" })` and `Rename("abc (1)", new [] { "abc (1) def" })`? (Again, the two differ by a space before `def`)

Comment: To counter the `\b` after `)` issue, change the closing `\b` to `(?:\b|(?<=\)))`: [`\babc\ \(1\)(?:\b|(?<=\)))`](https://regex101.com/r/echVwb/1/)